# How do you arrange four 4-ohm resistors to have a total resistance of 4-ohm?

Tags: resistors

I have some understanding of circuits and I have solved most of the problems in my homework, but I've come across then one seen in the title and can't solve it for some reason. If someone could please solve it, provide a diagram, and explain, that would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered connecting them in parallel?

Comment: I think I have seen a similar question before :) My take would be: take one of the resistors, drop the other 3 in your junk box. If your professor complains that you have to use all 4 of them, you connect one lead of each of the 3 to any point in the circuit you like. If he complains that you have to use the other lead too you connect it to the same point. If by now he does not understand how to formulate a question properly ("use 4 identical resistors as one of the same value but 4 times the allowed dissipation") he should look for an other job.

Comment: @woutervanooijen heh yes, but not quite fair - I've used four resistors to get higher power handling, same value.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen You are describing exactly the way I drove some middle/high-school (VWO) teachers to insanity. However, the question may be posed differently and summarised for the size of a title, of course.

Comment: In that case the blame is on whoever did that summarizing! (I am a HBO teacher now, and I am still trying to formulate my questions so they can't be misunderstood - and I fail quite regularly...)

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: If you solved it, please [edit] this answer to explain *how* you solved it: it may be helpful to others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I like it when you have 5x 4 ohm resistor and you have to make 4 ohms using all 5

Comment: @Andyaka I'm astounded, gobsmacked even, by how seldom that problem seems to arise in practice.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen When you attempt to make it idiot proof, nature will invent a better idiot.

Comment: In most cases it is not the idiots but the far-above-the-average students that manage to find a flaw in the formulation of a question. And for them I am more than willing to learn to formulate my questions better.

Answer (score 4):

For equal value resistors, the equations can be simplified as follows:

Two equal resistors in *parallel* are equivalent to one resistor of *half* the value.

Two equal resistors in *series* are equivalent to one resistor of *double* the value.

See what you can do from here.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a homework question I am not going to do exactly as you ask. With schematics and a full explanation you will not learn much. If you figure it out with a little help, you'll learn more.

(Although I'm sure within the day someone actually will do exactly what you ask, but hey)

First: Have you tried calculating the resistance of any of the combinations in parallel? 3 of them, 2 of them, 4 of them?

Second: What is the value of the resistance if you put a number of resistors with value X in series?

If you can answer those two questions correctly, you will find your solution by yourself.

If, in the comments you post the answers to those questions but still can't figure it out, I'll help you further. (I am also maintaining my motorcycle, so if someone else sees them pop up and wants to take over: be my guest)

Comment: You see I understand your point and I respect it in fact thanks. I did try to answer the question and try different combination,but I’ve been convinced that I am doing the calculations incorrectly. I've been using Ohm's Law where in a series it states Rt=r1+r2+r3+.. and in parallel 1/Rt=1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3 + ... I assume I'm using it correctly, but not understanding a certain trick there is with this subject. I'm only really understand as far as the book describes.

Comment: Those formulas are correct. So if all resistors were parallel, you'd get "1/Rt = 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 1" which gives Rt = 1, since 1/1 = 1. Let's say you'd have 3 resistors of 10 ohm. Can you see that putting them parallel gives 1/Rt = 0.3, so Rt = 1/0.3 = 3.33333? If you post the calculations you have done for the two questions as a response or an edit to your question, I can help you find what's going wrong.

Comment: @Marck That is the point of homework.  To force you to think.